# How to get the info_hash value of a .torrent file

Tags: c#, hash, sha1, bittorrent, torrent

I try to extract the info_hash data from a .torrent file but I can not.

I currently do my test with [this torrent file](https://archive.org/download/6201484321_f1a88ca2cb_b/6201484321_f1a88ca2cb_b_archive.torrent) but i found no way to get it. The doc says `The 20 byte sha1 hash of the bencoded form of the info value from the metainfo file. Note that this is a substring of the metainfo file.`

But even if I sha1 this string, this is not the right hash (I know what the right info_hash is because I tracked the uTorrent request with WireShark)

I am using the [Bencode](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bencode) package from NuGet to read the .torrent file and i extract the datas with

```csharp
var bencode = BencodeUtility.DecodeDictionary(File.ReadAllBytes(torrentfile));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in bencode)
{
  PrintKvp(kvp);
}
```

In PrintKvp(), when i find the "info" field, i print it with:

```csharp
if (kvp.Key == "info")
{
SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();

Console.WriteLine("info_hash : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sha1.ComputeHash(BencodeUtility.Encode(kvp.Value).ToArray())));
}
```

But the result is: `info_hash : ?ò?3??GZ?YA?h???&?`
This is obviously not a (human-readable) sha1 string...
How can I have a well encoded info_hash ? Thank you.

Comment: If you want human readable hash, simply convert it with the help of `Convert.ToBase64String()`, instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`.

Comment: With Convert.ToBase64String() the result is `rMOy5DPXx0dau1lBtWgct6HqJuI=` so it is human-readable but it still not the excepted return :/
The file is well formated.

Comment: base64 encoded `rMOy5DPXx0dau1lBtWgct6HqJuI=` is the same as the hex-encoded `ACC3B2E433D7C7475ABB5941B5681CB7A1EA26E2`, the expected result.

Comment: Thank You @Encombe this is exactly what i need :D